# Does the word "master" denote masculinity?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

The other day, I had a little argument with a friend. He asserted that if the principal of a school is a female, she would not be called a "headmaster", rather - a headmistress.

But I disagreed with him, saying that headmaster is a gender-neutral  term. I couldn't believe that people still used the word  "headmistress"

Turns out I was wrong. So my question is about the word "master" - does the word have some masculine origin?

Or is it that "mistress" goes with "mister"?

Comment: Adel, a gender-neutral term for it would be *headteacher* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/headteacher?q=headteacher , at least in the UK. From a British perspective, the word *principal* seems distinctly American.

Comment: To add further confusion: Pembroke College and St Catharine's College Oxford, and Yale University, have all had female Masters. The late Queen Mother was Lord Warden of the Cinque Ports; and the Queen is Duke of Lancaster and Duke of Normandy. The capital letters are important here, of course.

Comment: And even when I was a humble parish councillor we would address Madam Chairman! Though there were those who objected to this and would actually refer to 'the Chair', which Madam didn't like at all.

Comment: I have never ever heard of a woman being awarded a "mistress's degree".

Answer (score 19):

English is in a state of flux with regard to the use of gender-differentiated terms for professions and nationalities.  For some speakers (like my parents), female terms must be used when the referent is known to be female.  Such speakers have to say *she is a waitress*, not *she is a waiter*.

However, for other speakers (like me), words like *waitress*, *actress*, and *Frenchwoman* are, like *scrumptious* and *copacetic*, recognisable as English but usable only with ironic or pedantic undertones.  I would comfortably say *she is a waiter* to refer to what my parents call a waitress.

Not all such words have deteriorated at the same rate.  Where the female versions themselves refer to outmoded or old-fashioned professions or roles, I am happy to use the feminine, for instance, *washerwoman* or *nun*.  (But I would only use *nun* to refer a Christian.  In the past, I’ve referred to a Buddhist nun as a *monk*, leading an academic colleague to think I’d mistaken the woman for a man, because of her shaved head.  Being 40 years my senior, he wasn’t aware that *monk* in this context was simply gender neutral for me.)

Tying all of this back to your question: you’re both right, but you’re right about the conventions of different speech communities.  Your friend has correctly described a more conservative dialect.  You (like me) conform to a more innovative one.  I’m not sure that dictionaries have come to reflect this shift in usage.  But if you google "she is headmaster" / "she is a headmaster" / "she is the headmaster" (plus "-daughter" for convenience), you’ll appreciate that there are a reasonable number of speakers like us.

---

On the question of the origin of the *master*, @Jim correctly observes that *magister* is the Latin root of English *master*, and in Latin *magister* was a masculine word.  However, if you ask *Who was the greatest actor ever?*, this would not normally be taken to preclude a woman’s name being given in response.  In other words, masculine forms are default rather than male-specific.  (They require additional context for male-specific readings; e.g., *Excluding actresses, who was the greatest actor ever?*)  I’ve seen various studies of languages in which gender indication is obligatory (including French, Greek, Hebrew, Italian, Russian, Spanish), and the same holds there: masculine forms are (only with specific exceptions) default forms, covering both genders.  I don’t know if evidence is available for Latin, but my guess would be that, as a well behaved Indo-European language, it could reasonably be expected to behave similarly.

Comment: I certainly prefer "she is a waiter" to "she is a waitron", but there's no such long-standing neutral term as there is with *principal*. I don't know what you've got against *scrumptious*.

Comment: My dad’s use of _scrumptious_ when we were growing up used to send my brothers and me into a mix of cringes and giggles.  I’m willing to admit that that may be a family proclivity.

Comment: Does anyone understand the purpose of gender-neutral terms? Will it one day be out of order to refer to a man or a woman?

Comment: @WS2: yes, many people do.  I, for instance, can use the term _sibling_ magnificently, and my use of the term _spouse_ has been known to draw applause.

Comment: @DanielHarbour I fully understand why the idea of gender equality is sacrosanct. But I have never understood why a common gender identity should be promoted. Is not diversity the spice of life?

Comment: @WS2 Ah, I thought that’s what you were getting at (but your first comment was a bit too brief for me to be sure).  Gender equality is, at most, a secondary issue here.  The point for speakers like me is that the feminine forms simply sound old-fashioned (fine if you’re an older speaker or speak a conservative dialect) or pedantic (I’d be amazed to hear one of my contemporaries use these terms).  Admittedly, there’s gradation here, for the speakers I have in mind: _actress_ is sort of ok, _authoress_ pedantic, and _Jewess_ preposterous.  Are all of them equally usable for you?

Comment: @DanielHarbour I certainly say 'actress', 'waitress' and 'bar-maid'. I never have said 'Jewess'nor 'authoress'. What slightly concerns me is that you say you do not use the feminine forms because 'they sound old-fashioned'. This points to a circular downhill screwing process which is going on. Seems to me as if society may disappear up its own rectal orifice at this rate. But since I am retired I can do as I like -though I have not so far got round to carrying a talking parrot on my shoulder like Long John Silver.

Comment: Let's try to wrap this up rather than have prolonged discussion in comments. 1: Yes, definitely, do the parrot thing.  My aunt had a talking parrot and she’d say _authoress_.  2: I understand that dumping _-ess_ forms might seem like political correctness; for some people it may be.  But I emphasise—again—that, at least for some speakers (incl. me), these forms are non-contemporary rather than non-PC.  We’re just following your lead in having ceased to add _-ess_ to _author_.

Comment: @WS2 RE your original comment: I hope so.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Could it involve surgery?

Comment: This state of flux is artificially forced by feminist movement, isn't it? Well, it's the irony that feminists in Poland force the usage of feminine forms for occupations, using the same arguments. My logic teacher have told me, that the false argument can imply contradicting anwers (leaving implication correct). Just a side argument.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. yes, it is. And it's IMO utterly idiotic. Netherlands are now similar. Job listings stating (translated) "looking for a waitress F/M" or similar.

Comment: @ŁukaszL: the state of flux is in any case necessitated by a change in the workforce. A term is necessary for "a waiter or waitress and I don't care which". A century ago is was sufficiently rare to not care about the gender that some neutral terms are/were missing from English. You can credit that change in the workforce to the feminist movement if you like, but I don't think it's artificial, nor is it purely linguistic. What is open to influence (from feminists or others) is what the neutral terms are going to be: Daniel chooses "waiter", Dutch restaurants apparently chose "waitress F/M" :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I refer something opposite, namely requesting to invent femininum occupation names for the masculinum occupation names, even if the new words sounds awful. So in English where there were 2 forms, a single is forged, while in Polish 2nd form is forged, where a single one existed. Both are justified by the same arguments.

Comment: @ŁukaszL: ah, I thought by "this state of flux" you referred to "English is in a state of flux" at the top of Daniel's answer. If Polish is in a different state of flux then I can't speak to that or to its causes, I just speak for English :-) The flux in English is certainly inconsistent: in some cases the female term has been more or less dropped ("authoress", "poetess") as a needless distinction. In other cases both gendered terms have been dropped and replaced, "headteacher" being one of them. In still others the gendered terms remain with the male form as a catch-all ("actor" / "actress").

Comment: ... there may be a few cases in English where a female term has been invented ("chairwoman" comes to mind), but I can't off-hand think of any that are widely accepted. For a while there was a weird thing that it seemed a male chair was a "chairman" and a female chair a "chairperson", but I think that's being knocked on the head now in favour of genuinely neutral terms.

Comment: As a gender neutral term for waiter/waitress, I use "server".

Comment: @ŁukaszL: can you give us some examples of newly feminized words?

Answer (score 8):

If you were to look up the two words ([headmaster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headmaster) and [headmistress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headmistress)), you would see that they are the man and woman, respectively, who is the head of a U.S. private school or a British school.

Furthermore, the two words, master and mistress, can be traced to the Old French words, maistre and maistresse, and the Modern French words,  maître and maîtresse.

Both are derived from the Latin magister, from which we also get "magistrate" (magistratus).

So to answer your question ("does the word *master* have some masculine origin?), you can look at the definition in [The Latin Dictionary](http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun%3amagister), where it states that *magister* is a masculine noun. In Latin, nouns have fixed gender, and in this case it is masculine. This differs from the Romantic languages that descended from Vulgar Latin (as in non-standard, common, as opposed to classical Latin), where it is common to have both masculine and feminine forms of some nouns.

([reference link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=maistre&searchmode=none))

Comment: I’m not sure that dictionary definitions are what OP is after here.  I took the question as wanting to determine whether those definitions are still accurate.  What you write certainly holds of many speakers' English, but for others the gender distinction is a vanishing feature of the language.  Check out my answer and let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Oops, sorry @Jim : I take that comment back.  *I* misunderstood the question! :-0

Comment: What about the Latina dictionary?

Answer (score 7):

In theory, *mistress* is the precise female equivalent of *master*, being the translation of Latin *domina* rather than *dominus*. In practice *master* (particularly as a verb) is used in many contexts where dominance is more relevant than gender, and *mistress* is used only in a few specialised contexts. Education is one of them: though *games teacher* is a neutral term, a *games mistress* is always female, and one of the senior bodies in British independent education is called the "Headmasters' and Headmistresses' Conference" (confusingly abbreviated to HMC).

Comment: I don't know if NASUWT still exists (National Association of Schoolmasters and Union of Women Teachers). It was a rival of the NUT (National Union of Teachers)

Comment: I'd use the term "master" for a woman only when it denotes having mastered a skill. Like "she is a master carpenter".

Comment: @WS2 NASUWT still exists but the name isn't trying to make any kind of a point about differences in terminology for male and female teachers: it's an artifact of the union's formation by the merger of the National Association of Schoolmasters and the Union of Women Teachers in the 1970s. I guess they wanted to retain the "brand recognition" of the existing names, rather than make up a new one. (Ironically, the NAS was originally the National Association of Men Teachers [sic], which broke away from the NUT in opposition to the NUT's 1919 endorsement of equal pay for male and female teachers.)

Comment: @jwenting And your master carpenter probably doesn't have a Mistress of Arts degree. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nor even a Spinster of Arts degree! And yes, I had a friend, in the 1960s who defended his membership of the NAS entirely on the original grounds. What was a reasonable salary for a woman married to a professional husband, he argued, (and many leaders in the NUT were well-off married women) was unacceptable for 'a married man' with a wife who looked after children and 'didn't go out to work'. It was a vehemently held opinion in much of society at a time before good child-care facilities became available, and women working became fashionable.

Comment: Language is not my first language, so I would use master for  female. Because for me `mistress` is female lover. How "wrong" am I?

Answer (score 5):

In Britain, when I was at school, (1950s) the head was always a headmaster or a headmistress. Single-sex education was far more common than it is today. Boys' schools had headmasters and girls' headmistresses.

The terms survived the move to co-education and certainly well through the time that my children were at school in the 1980s and 90s, their heads were either Headmasters or Headmistresses.

More recently there has been a move away from the terms to calling them simply 'Head'. 'The Head wants to see you in his/her study'.

The other teachers, in my day were known as masters and mistresses, though those terms have mostly given way to 'teachers'. However in a lot of traditional schools they do remain. There is perhaps still a slightly higher cachet associated with giving your occupation as 'schoolmaster' rather than plain 'schoolteacher'.

Comment: There was and is no reason why a girls' school should not have a headmaster. But +1 for the overview.

Comment: WS2 in more recent times, the word *headteacher* has been in common use, in British schools. *Headmaster* and *headmistress* have been less common.

Comment: @Tristanr Yes, of course, why did I not include that? - Headteacher is the current word.

Comment: @TimLymington not in theory, in practice however commonly boys' schools had almost exclusively male staff, girls' schools female staff. This might stem back to the times when such schools were run by the church, placing nuns in charge of educating girls and friars of educating boys (my father went to such a friar run boys' school, which was next door to the nun run girls' school in the town he lived in in the 1940s).

Comment: @jwenting The development of state education, from the 1860s was very closely related to the Churches. The British method was simply to hand the job over to religious bodies and give state funding. In France, on the other hand, church and state were, after the Revolution, ideologically separated so the French state created a universal system which was, in theory, the same everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

"Master" has at least two slightly different uses. It's gendered up to a point, with "mistress" the female form.

One use means (roughly) a person in authority over one or more others, as for example a teacher over students or an employer over household servants, and there are several specific relationships it has been most commonly used for. This usage traditionally was strongly gendered.

"Headmaster" is this first usage, but the "master" refers to the teachers that the head is in charge of (the headmaster is the head among the masters), not the headmaster himself (he is *not* the master of heads). In schools with both sexes of teacher, "master" is being used to mean all "masters and mistresses" (the male embraces the female). So I don't suppose that it would be technically incorrect to refer to a woman as the headmaster. However, I don't think it's done in practice: those who care to skip the tradition of gendered titles will use "headteacher" or "head". You could even perhaps argue that it's a kind of inaccuracy (despite being established usage) to call a woman in charge of men, or of a mixed group of men and women, the "headmistress". This doesn't change the usage, of course, and any argument based on referring to a mixed group by the male form but a female group by the female form is going to seem out-dated.

"Mistress" does *also* go with "Mister", because "Mister" was originally a variant of "Master" although the two are no longer interchangeable as titles. "Mrs." was originally a variant of "Mistress". Just to be confusing, so was "Miss" and so is "Ms."

As an aside, the other use means (roughly) a person who is expert in their profession ("a master craftsman") and I think is less gendered. I speculate that in the relevant centuries, women were rarely considered experts in their professions! Of course such people might well have a managerial role as well, but I do not believe that is what "master" refers to here. Rather, they are "masters" of their craft.

There isn't any such phrase as "mistress craftswoman", but you could say "mistress of her craft". You also might say "master craftswoman" if you want a gendered term, "master craftsman" if you apply male gendered terms to both men and women, "master crafter" or whatever if you prefer a neutral term and are willing to accept "master" as neutral in this context. Each strategy exists, irrespective of what we think of them, and not everyone uses one strategy exclusively for all kinds of gendered term.

"Master" is also a verb, and there is no corresponding verb "to mistress".

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, the word *master* does not denote masculinity.

The verb and adjective forms are utterly without controversy, and you could easily, intuitively write sentences like "She mastered the school's technique" or "She is a master bassist."

The noun form is only controversial to the most hardline traditionalists. Notwithstanding their objections from the fringes of society, you could otherwise write sentences like "She is master of the ship" without attracting argument.

Nor does the word *master* itself have a male-specific etymological base. It derives from the Latin *magnus*, which is a masculine word in the sense that Latin had a grammatical gender, but not in the sense that somehow the concept of *magn-* could only be applied to males. (And there was the feminine equivalent *magna*.)

So, whence does the controversy arise?

It's because, in the past, people believed that it was very important to know whether the holder of any given role was male or female. And they structured their societies--and gave so few rights to females--such that in many instances it actually was important to know. I'll get back to this point in a moment.

In modern times we have largely divorced roles from any explicit sex-specificity, and a person's sex therefore doesn't matter in the consideration of the roles that person performs. The chairperson's sex has no bearing on that person's ability to be chair, nor does the firefighter's sex, nor the waiter's, nor the actor's, and so forth.

But old ideas do not die easily, and there are still many people who insist that we should use role descriptors to also indicate a person's sex, even though the usefulness is obsolete. And there are bits and pieces in the English language onto which these diehard traditionalists cling.

The best such example, in the context of your query about the worst *master*, is the word *mistress*, the feminized corruption of *master* by way of Old French. In olden times many roles existed as sex pairs. A landed estate would have had a master, denoting that individual's authority over the affairs of his house. Quite often the master would have been married, and his wife would have been granted considerable parallel authority under her husband to govern those affairs of the house traditionally identified as being within the distaff domain (i.e., women's affairs). To convey this concept quickly, the word *mistress* arose to denote the master's female counterpart.

These days such a usage is virtually obsolete. Exceptions do still exist; the White House still has a traditional mistress-type role for the First Lady; nonetheless the role has become an anachronism as today most couples divide their domestic affairs circumstantially, without respect to sex, and with each successive generation this de-gendering of roles is becoming more thorough.

Be that as it may, the fact that the actual, historical role of *mistress* is obsolete poses no dissuasion to those who still believe that we must use roles to identify people's sex. To these traditionalists, a female of any sort of authority is a *mistress*, never a *master*, and thus, to them, the term *master* is masculine and reserved for male use (although they would not object to the verb and adjectival forms of the word).

I would be negligent to finish this reply without a few words on the feminine diminutive more broadly, of which *mistress* is but one instance. The most common feminine diminutives in English are *-ess* (as with *mistress*) and *-ette* (as with *bachelorette*). By their nature, feminine diminutives are degrading, implying that somehow for a female to hold a role means they alter the role itself to reflect their sex. The English-speaking world has been moving away from the feminine diminuative for a long time, and another commenter made an excellent example of this gradation in action by invoking the words *waitress*, which many people still accept (though some think of it as quaint), *authoress*, which virtually no one uses, and *Jewess*, which is nowadays used only as an offensive slur.

In all likelihood this trend will continue as society continues toward its recognition that a person's sex is independent of their capacity to fulfill a role, like that of author, and moreover that being a female does not make for an inferior individual. Specialized exceptions will linger the longest, like *actress*, because the film industry segregates awards.

Thus, for all the protestations of the hardliners, in my assessment you can safely ignore them and use *master* of females howsoever you wish.

Lastly, here's a bit of data: The words *master* and *mistress* have both in sustained long-term decline, with a minor resurgence recently that may or may not be statistical noise. Either way, the data suggest that the very concept of mastership is fading from the social currency, and with it the tagalong concept of the mistress. That's in addition to the decline in *mistress* as a result of our society becoming less sexist.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=master%2C+mistress&year_start=1500&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmistress%3B%2Cc0

Comment: +1 - excellent argument for your point. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Excellent writing on the subject, though I believe “worst _master_” is a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Both *master* and *mister* come from latin *magister* that is masculin for *chief*, *teacher*, feminine being *magistra*.

In English, *mistress* is the feminine form of *master*, it comes from French *maitresse*, which in turn comes from Latin.

The usage is then up to you, in modern times, in English, it's common to use the masculine form to denote both genders.

Answer (score 1):

It does.

Generally, the term *principal* would be used, rather than either *headmaster* or *headmistress*, because *principal* is gender-neutral.

After all, why should one use *headmaster* of women, not *headmistress* of men?

Comment: In Britain, they're *head teachers*,, although that makes me envision someone at a podium addressing a room of disembodied heads.

Comment: @choster, and sometimes just *heads*.

Comment: choster, that's a good point. The word *principal*, is not normally used in this context, in the UK.

Comment: @Tristanr it certainly was in the UK schools I went to.

Comment: Jon, like many other things in life and the universe, there are exceptions to what is normal.

Comment: @Tristanr but is my experience the exception, or yours?

Comment: Jon, considering your experience, it seems that will depend on where exactly in the UK, someone goes to school.

Comment: As a Brit I've never heard the word "principal" used except on American TV etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Master* is actually the forerunner of *Mister*. It used to be used to refer to men and boys.

In modern English, *mister* (or *mr.*) is used to address men, while *master* is used as a form of address only for boys.

About the word *headmaster* or *schoolmaster* specifically, Wikipedia states that:

> "The word schoolmaster, or simply master, formerly referred to a male school teacher. This usage survives in British independent schools, both secondary and "preparatory", but is generally obsolete elsewhere."

Comment: Some University colleges have a 'Master' as the head e.g. The Master of Trinity College, Cambridge. I am not sure what happens when the post is held by a woman. Does she become the Mistress of Trinity ?

Comment: @WS2 No: see my comment on the question.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer is, yes... Master defines masculinity and mistress as feminine, you can't change original English for political term... Actually even in many fields a male with great eligibility is master and female is mistress. Master is totally gender based(a male) and not by authority or capability... Even master craftman is male and female should be mistress craftwoman(you know, the actual English)... Same to many other fields we're master/mistress  is used as suffix/prefix...

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please improve your answer by adding links to sources.